# Switching layout whit onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, layout

I want to switch between layouts using the physical back button. I found this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
RelativeLayout layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);// check if layout2 is open
if(layout2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    return;
}else{
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    }

}
```

Is the checking part correct?

Comment: What problem are you facing with this code, please elaborate

Comment: I'm not a good java programmer, i found this java code on Stackoverflow and i only want to know if this code could help me

Comment: This code will switch your layout only when layout2 is visible, otherwise it will take you back(default behaviour of physical back key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `RelativeLayout` decalre globally so you can access in `OnBack()` method

```
 RelativeLayout layout2
```

this line you have to put in the `OnCreate()` method

```
 layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);//
```

and finally check `visibility` of `layout`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(layout2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    return;
}else{
    super.onBackPressed(); 
    }

}
```

enjoy coding............

Comment: And if i have more then 2 layouts?

Comment: what you mean of 2 layouts ... Is you want to change layout form one to another....

Comment: I mean like in a simple application. If I have 3 pages, when I'm on the third, if I press the back button the app will change from layout3 to layout2. Same thing whit the layout1.

Comment: you have to maintain a integer and checking condition of that integer ....like  `if(i==0) setContentView(R.layout.main1); else if(i==1) setContentView(R.layout.main2); else setContentView(R.layout.main3);` and maintain the integer value in every condintion.